# vsftp homedirs outside /home

Tags: ftp, ubuntu-13.04

I've got vsftp setup with an Ubuntu (13.04) server with two separate hard drives. One for the OS, another is a large software RAID. Currently my FTP users have home directories under */home*. Because the OS drive is small I want to move those users' homedirs to the */var/raid/ftp-user-x* directories instead.

Now I've created the new user directories by hand, changed the user accounts with `usermod` and copied over all files preserving permissions. I've verified the new directories are being used by `grep`ing for respective usernames in */etc/passwd*.

Despite restarting vsftpd, having changed the location of the home directories, when I try to connect my FTP client times out. I'm finding it difficult to get much of anything useful out of the logs with vsftp.

How can I get vsftp to work with FTP users' home directories inside */var/raid*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get vsftpd to point at another directory by adding/changing the below option to your vsftpd.conf file :

local_root=/var/raid/$USER

Please be aware that this will also look for the user folder. If you want all users to login to the same directory remove "/$USER"

Comment: That didn't quite get it for me, but lead me down the right direction. I've taken the approach of splitting the config per [this thread](http://serverfault.com/questions/222906/vsftpd-local-root-var-www-sites-user-doesnt-get-interpreted). It's working for me now; thanks!